# In Euler-Lagrange equation, why don't we use a partial derivative for the time?

Tags: partial-derivative, euler-lagrange-equation

The Euler-Lagrange equation is typically written in this form :

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\mathcal{L}=0
\end{equation}

Since the Lagrangian is a functional form of $t$, $q$, $\dot{q}$, why do we use a full derivative for the time, instead of a *partial derivative* ?

Comment: If you read a proof that derives this equation from a suitable optimisation problem, you can see that the total derivative appears quite naturally. An answer to this question will most likely just copy a proof for you and point out where the total derivative happens. It is better if you read through a proof yourself and ask us to explain the parts you don't get.

Comment: I tend to believe that the reason for the total derivative is that my question is *wrong* : the Lagrangian does not depend on time ?

Comment: The Lagrangian may depend on time, and for a given solution path, the position $q$ and velocity $\dot q$ _definitely_ depend on time in most cases. So the total derivative makes sense there and is also correct.

Comment: A partial derivative would only track the EXPLICIT time dependence - often a Lagrangian will only depend on time implicitly, through its dependence on $q$ and $\dot q$

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanations.

Comment: Related Phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321668/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Arthur's advice is to revisit the standard proof of the ELE, in which an integration by parts with vanishing boundary terms gives $\int\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}\delta\dot{q}dt=-\int\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}\right)\delta qdt$. So the real question is why this IBP has the form$$\int_a^bu\frac{dv}{dt}dt=[uv]_a^b-\int_a^b\frac{du}{dt}vdt.$$By the FTA, this reduces to asking why the product rule should be $\frac{d(uv)}{dt}=u\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{du}{dt}v$, instead of something similar in which a partial time derivative appears at least once.

In the case at hand $q$ is a function of time alone, since the action is a single integral. Then $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}$, being a function of $q,\,\dot{q}$, reduces to a function of time only.

Your question concerns classical mechanics, so we should contrast it with an ELE from classical field theory. The role of time is replaced with multiple variables $x^\mu$; the role of $q$ is replaced with a field, say $\phi$. An action of the form $S=\int\mathcal{L}(\phi,\,\partial\phi/\partial x^\mu)d^nx$ has ELE$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial\phi/\partial x^\mu)}-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}=0$$(with [implicit summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) over $\mu$). You'll notice the generalization of $\frac{d}{dt}$, namely $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$, *is* a partial derivative.